# How to manually clean the call stack created by Self invoking function

Tags: javascript, callstack

```
(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
        // some function
    },3000);
})();
```

Above code runs inside a for loop, what i want is that i should be able to prevent the execution of the `setTimeout` call stack that gets executed when timeout occurs and should be able to clean it.

Comment: What do you mean "should be able to clean it" ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you executed the IIFE in this way and you wanted to clear the timeout which was issued from inside the for-loop:

```js
for(let i=0; i< 4; i++){
    (()=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("done");
        },3000);
    })();
}
```

In this case `setTimeout()` returns an `id` using which you can clear the timeouts issued:

```js
const arr = []
for(let i=0; i< 4; i++){
    (()=>{
        let id = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("done");
        },3000);
        arr.push(id);
    })();
}
arr.forEach((id)=>clearTimeout(id)); //done not printed in console as timeout was cancelled
```